# MySQL: Merge 3 similar but not identical rows

Tags: mysql, merge

How to combine rows containing synonyms ?

```
1st row: **THE STUDY** researches the metabolites produced by virus.
2nd row: The research **INVESTIGATES** the metabolites produced by virus.
3nd row: The research investigates the metabolites **EXCRETED** by virus.
```

Merging result will be:

```
The study investigates the metabolites excreted by virus.
```

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL? How do you decide which words are synonyms? How do you decide which of the synonym is to be used?

Comment: "Study" is synonymous with "research",
"investigate" is synonymous with "research" 
"produced" is synonymous with "excreted" (in this context).
Maybe, I should have table of synonyms.